# Get the entire row with a max specific value,Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas

```
neighbourhood      room_type           value
Agios Loukas       Entire home/apt      69
                   Private room         11
                   Shared room           1
Agios Nikolaos     Entire home/apt     193
                   Private room         33
Akadimia Platonos  Entire home/apt      45
                   Private room         10
                   Shared room           1
```

What is the best way to take the entire row with max value.
For example  i want to take

```
Agios Loukas       Entire home/apt      69 
Agios Nikolaos     Entire home/apt     193
Akadimia Platonos  Entire home/apt      45
```

Thank you and sorry for my english

Comment: Ι tried this 
**df.max( level = 'neighbourhood')**   
but it only gave me  the neighbourhood and the value

Comment: You are looking to get the row with the highest value in each neighborhood, is that correct? Also, in this case, do all the rows have a value for the neighborhood column?

Comment: @hotvector Yes, exactly

Comment: `df.groupby('neighbourhood')['value'].max()`

Comment: @hotvector 
Per neighbourhood   i have  one or more room_types and i want to print for every neighbourhood  the name of the room_type that has the maximum value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need;

Either groupby on the first level and `idxmax` with `df.loc[]`

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['value'].idxmax()]
print(out)
```

---

```
                                   value
neighbourhood     room_type             
Agios Loukas      Entire home/apt     69
Agios Nikolaos    Entire home/apt    193
Akadimia Platonos Entire home/apt     45
```

Or:

`groupby+transform` with max and then equals operator to compate and select the rows

```
out1 = df[df['value'].eq(df.groupby('neighbourhood')['value'].transform('max'))]
print(out1)

                                   value
neighbourhood     room_type             
Agios Loukas      Entire home/apt     69
Agios Nikolaos    Entire home/apt    193
Akadimia Platonos Entire home/apt     45
```

Comment: **out = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['value'].idxmax()]** works fine

Answer (score 0):

Use .max() to get the max value of a column, and put it inside of a df.loc[] request to get all the rows with that value. Something like this:

```
df.loc[df['value'] == df['value'].max()]
```